# Seeking shapefile of Districts Cyprus in vector format

Tags: geospatial, map

Where do I find the shapefile of Cyprus communities?

I am referring to the small black polygons that made the districts - Famagusta, Kyrenia, Larnaca, Limassol, Nicosia and Paphos in the picture below.

Gadm.org has only level0 and level1. What I needed is probably level2 or level3?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the [National Open Data Portal](https://www.data.gov.cy/), in which data of most Cypriot public bodies are available for further use.

[Administrative Boundaries of Municipalities and Communities - Administrative Map](https://www.data.gov.cy/dataset/%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC-%CF%8C%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CE%B4%CE%AE%CE%BC%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9-%CE%BA%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%84%CE%AE%CF%84%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B7%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82-%CF%87%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82)